# Sorting a list of objects with Swift based on their distance to the device location

Tags: swift

So I have a list of objects I get from a network request that have `latitude` and `longitude` properties. My goal is to have the objects sorted by proximity to the device's current location. I have a solution that works, but I feel as if there is a more elegant implementation of this.

Here's my current function:

```
func sortItems(items: [Item]) -> [Item] {
    var distanceDictionary: [Int: Double] = [:]
    
    guard let location = DefaultsWrapper.shared.lastLocation else {
        return items
    }
    
    items.forEach { item in
        let itemLocation = CLLocation(latitude: item.latitude, longitude: item.longitude)
        let distance = item.distance(from: location)
        distanceDictionary[item.id] = distance
    }
    
    var sortedItemIds: [Int] = []
    
    for (k, _) in (Array(distanceDictionary).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
        sortedItemIds.append(k)
    }
    
    var sortedItems: [Item] = []
    
    sortedItemIds.forEach { id in
        let itemIndex = items.firstIndex { item in
            item.itemId == id
        }
        
        if let index = itemIndex {
            sortedItems.append(items[index])
        }
    }
    
    return sortedItems
}
```

Anyone have a way that I could simplify this code or perhaps make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func sortItems(items: [Item]) -> [Item] {

guard let location = DefaultsWrapper.shared.lastLocation else {
    return items
}

return items.sorted(by:{$0.distance(from: location) < $1.distance(from: location) })
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I had to change it to this: `items.sorted(by:{CLLocation(latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude).distance(from: location) < CLLocation(latitude: $1.latitude, longitude: $1.longitude).distance(from: location) })` but it works perfectly! Thanks so much!